# Python Merge function array range error?

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, mergesort

I am trying to merge two lists but getting errors. Anybody has an idea?

Below is my merge function.

```
 def mymerg(container, first_index, mid_index, last_index):
      left_list = container[:mid_index]
      right_list = container[mid_index:]
      i = 0
      j = 0
      for elem in range(first_index, last_index+1, 1):
           if left_list[i] <= right_list[j]:
                container[elem] = left_list[i]
                i = i + 1
           else:
                container[elem] = right_list[j]
                j = j + 1
```

And here is my sort function that generates error in the line My_Merge_Sort(container, first_index, mid_index)

```
    def mymgsor(container, first_index, last_index):
            if first_index < last_index:
                    mid_index = len(container)//2
                    mymgsor(container, first_index, mid_index)
                    mymgsor(container, mid_index+1, last_index)
                    mymerg(container, first_index, mid_index, last_index)
```

And I am also getting this error if first_index < last_index: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison. What is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

When I call this function I use mymgsor(sample_list, 0, len(sample_list)-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`heapq.merge`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) instead of implementing your own.

```
>>> import heapq
>>> list(heapq.merge([1,3,5], [2,4,6,7,8]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

---

Using heapq.merge:

```
>>> def mymgsor(container, first_index, last_index):
...     if first_index < last_index:
...         mid_index = (last_index+first_index) // 2
...         mymgsor(container, first_index, mid_index)
...         mymgsor(container, mid_index+1, last_index)
...         container[first_index:last_index+1] = heapq.merge(container[first_index:mid_index+1], container[mid_index+1:last_index+1])
...
>>> xs = [5,4,2,3,1]
>>> mymgsor(xs, 0, len(xs)-1)
>>> xs
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

### Reason of RuntimeError:

Following line always produce same value; cause infinite recursion of `mymgsor`:

```
mid_index = len(container)//2
```

`mymerg` calculate indice wrong. Try following:

```
def mymerg(container, first_index, mid_index, last_index):
    left_list = container[first_index:mid_index+1]   # copy only  first_index .. mid_index
    right_list = container[mid_index+1:last_index+1] # copy only mid_index+1 .. last_index
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for elem in range(first_index, last_index+1, 1):
        if left_list[i] <= right_list[j]:
            container[elem] = left_list[i]
            i += 1
            if i == len(left_list): # no more left
                container[elem+1:last_index+1] = right_list[j:]
                break
        else:
            container[elem] = right_list[j]
            j += 1
            if j == len(right_list): # no more right
                container[elem+1:last_index+1] = left_list[i:]
                break
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!! So I tried mid_index = (first_index + last_index)//2  but still not working. Any idea? Thanks though!

Comment: @dfsadxsadqwd213, I added alternative mymgsor using `heapq.merge`.

Comment: @dfsadxsadqwd213, You original code calculate indices wrong way in `mymerg`.

Comment: Do you mean in the mymerg, I am doing the indexing wrong? In the mymsgor, I corrected as you suggest, and it works! Thanks

Comment: @dfsadxsadqwd213, Yes, I mean it.

Comment: Thanks. But I did exactly the same thing as in the Algorithm textbook, CLRS and can't understand what is wrong with my mymerg function. Could you help? Or some hint?

Comment: @dfsadxsadqwd213, I added modified `mymerg`.